# COUNTIF not Working for Less Than a Year Value

Tags: countif

As shown in the images the `COUNTIF` statement works for the `N/A` cells. However, it does not work for less than a specific year (e.g., `< 2010` returns `0` even though there are lots of years less than 2010).

I tried formatting the year cells in the "MASTER" sheet as numbers instead of text but this did not help.

Cells containing `COUNTIF`:

[image: cells containing countif]

Reference cells from "MASTER" sheet containing years:

[image: reference cells from 'MASTER' sheet containing years]

Example of formula used for years less than 2010:

[image: example of formula used for years less than 2010]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell values are stored as Text, not Numbers. You can generally tell by the left-aligned values in the cell, as well as the fact that the condition isn't working as expected.

I know you said you tried formatting the values as numbers rather than text, but that won't change the existing values in the cells until they're edited.

I often find it useful to copy + paste the column into a plain text editor, then copy + paste back into the sheet with the correct formatting.

Comment: The issue I am finding with this that there are some cells which don't contain anything and some cells that contain "N/A". Is it possible to convert all the numbers from text to number format even with these non number cells inbetween?

Comment: Yeah, just format the column as Number before pasting back in the data